# xgboost reduce float precision does not reduce train time

Tags: xgboost

I expected that reducing the precision of my data (e.g., from int64 to int8) would speed up the training.
But, even if I reduce the overall size of my dataset by 74%, I do not see an improvement.
Is this expected?

Comment: In case you are using XGBoost for Python: do you pass your data as DMatrix()?

Comment: no, as a Pandas dataframe

Comment: Why is there an expectation that reducing the data type size would reduce training time?

Comment: Because it would reduce memory usage. Why does it not make sense?

Comment: It probably won't play a role in case you are training on all available data **and that data fits into memory as a whole**. However, if your data does not fit into memory then this will reduce the process of loading data into memory continuously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing float precision cannot make any difference as ["XGBoost treats all data as 32-bit float internally."](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/8376)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass the data directly as `DMatrix()`, *XGBoosts* internal data type. As stated in the [official documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.core):

> DMatrix is an internal data structure that is used by XGBoost, which
> is **optimized for both memory efficiency and training speed**. You can
> construct DMatrix from multiple different sources of data.

I think this also answers your question, since *XGBoost* is optimized for `DMatrix()`, the impact of changes like yours will be small at best.

Comment: Using the Learning API actually sped up almost 7X the train time. Thanks!
But, again, reducing the float precision did not improve the performance.